# SVG animation: scale multiple figures from their respective origin in a single .svg file

Tags: animation, svg, loader, svg-animate

I want to have a loader with three pulsating and fading stars. I already created this loader with CSS, but this technique is not appropriate for this case. I want to have a single loader.svg file.

Here is a pen with the CSS version:

https://codepen.io/Joan_Na/pen/wvawzEb 
This is what it should look like.

Here is my approach for the single SVG file:

https://codepen.io/Joan_Na/pen/gOpYwNy 
I can't get the stars scaling from their respective origins. It would also be nice to start the animation of each star seperately, like in the CSS example above.

Here is the SVG file code:

```html
<div class="container">
<svg width="90px" height="30px" viewBox="0 0 90 30" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<linearGradient id="SVGID_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="44.9437" y1="-0.0694" x2="45.0305" y2="19.8832">
 <stop  offset="0.155" style="stop-color:#FEFE7B"/>
 <stop  offset="0.2795" style="stop-color:#FEFC75"/>
 <stop  offset="0.4527" style="stop-color:#FEF663"/>
 <stop  offset="0.6546" style="stop-color:#FEED45"/>
 <stop  offset="0.8763" style="stop-color:#FDE01C"/>
 <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#FDD802"/>
</linearGradient>
 <polygon id="star1" fill="url(#SVGID_1_)" points="45,6 47.93,11.92 54.47,12.87 49.73,17.49 50.85,24 45,20.93 39.15,24 40.27,17.49 
  35.53,12.87 42.07,11.92" transform="translate(-30 0)"/>
  <animateTransform
   attributeName="transform" 
   attributeType="XML" 
   type="scale"
   dur="1s" 
   values="1;0;1"
   repeatCount="indefinite" 
   begin="0s"  
   calcMode="linear"/>
  <animate
   attributeName="opacity"
   values="1;0;1" 
   dur="1s"
   repeatCount="indefinite" 
   begin="0s" 
   calcMode="linear"/>
<polygon id="star2" fill="url(#SVGID_1_)" points="45,6 47.93,11.92 54.47,12.87 49.73,17.49 50.85,24 45,20.93 39.15,24 40.27,17.49 
 35.53,12.87 42.07,11.92 " transform="translate(0 0)"/>
 <animateTransform
   attributeName="transform" 
   attributeType="XML" 
   type="scale"
   dur="1s" 
   values="1;0;1"
   repeatCount="indefinite" 
   begin="0s"  
   calcMode="linear"/>
  <animate
   attributeName="opacity"
   values="1;0;1" 
   dur="1s"
   repeatCount="indefinite" 
   begin="0s" 
   calcMode="linear"/>
<polygon id="star3" fill="url(#SVGID_1_)" points="45,6 47.93,11.92 54.47,12.87 49.73,17.49 50.85,24 45,20.93 39.15,24 40.27,17.49 
 35.53,12.87 42.07,11.92 " transform="translate(30 0)"/>
 <animateTransform
   attributeName="transform" 
   attributeType="XML" 
   type="scale"
   dur="1s" 
   values="1;0;1"
   repeatCount="indefinite" 
   begin="0s"  
   calcMode="linear"/>
  <animate
   attributeName="opacity"
   values="1;0;1" 
   dur="1s"
   repeatCount="indefinite" 
   begin="0s"
   calcMode="linear" />

</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent the stars from shifting during the `scale ()` transform, I applied CSS rules

```
#star1, #star2, #star3  {
transform-origin: center;
transform-box:fill-box;
}
```

Since this CSS rule does not work together with the SVG transformation command `transform =" translate ()"` I had to use my own separate `path` for each star.

```css
.container {
background:#000;
width:30vw;
height:15vh;
padding-left:30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="90" height="30" viewBox="0 0 90 30" version="1.1">

<linearGradient id="SVGID_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="44.9437" y1="-0.0694" x2="45.0305" y2="19.8832">
 <stop  offset="0.155" style="stop-color:#FEFE7B"/>
 <stop  offset="0.2795" style="stop-color:#FEFC75"/>
 <stop  offset="0.4527" style="stop-color:#FEF663"/>
 <stop  offset="0.6546" style="stop-color:#FEED45"/>
 <stop  offset="0.8763" style="stop-color:#FDE01C"/>
 <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#FDD802"/>
</linearGradient> 
 <path id="star1" fill="url(#SVGID_1_)" d="m 20.9062,24.304922 -5.85,-3.07 -5.85,3.07 1.12,-6.51 -4.74,-4.62 6.54,-0.95 2.93,-5.9200004 2.93,5.9200004 6.54,0.95 -4.74,4.62 z" style="transform-origin: center; transform-box:fill-box;" >
      <animateTransform id="an_T1"
   attributeName="transform" 
   attributeType="XML" 
   type="scale"
   dur="1s" 
   values="1;0;1"
   repeatCount="indefinite" 
   begin="0s"
      keyTimes="0;0.75;1"
      />
  <animate id="an_Op1"
   attributeName="opacity"
   values="1;0;1" 
   dur="1s"
   repeatCount="indefinite" 
   begin="0s"
      keyTimes="0;0.75;1"
      /> 
 </path>
 
 

 <path id="star2"  fill="url(#SVGID_1_)" d="M 54.47,12.87 49.73,17.49 50.85,24 45,20.93 39.15,24 40.27,17.49 35.53,12.87 42.07,11.92 45,6 l 2.93,5.92 z" style="transform-origin: center; transform-box:fill-box;" >
      <animateTransform id="an_T2"
   attributeName="transform" 
   attributeType="XML" 
   type="scale"
   dur="1s" 
   values="1;0;1"
   repeatCount="indefinite" 
   begin="0.2s"
      keyTimes="0;0.75;1"
      />
  <animate id="an_Op2"
   attributeName="opacity"
   values="1;0;1" 
   dur="1s"
   repeatCount="indefinite" 
   begin="0.2s"
      keyTimes="0;0.75;1"
      /> 
 </path> 



  <path id="star3" fill="url(#SVGID_1_)" d="m 79.700565,18.010534 1.12,6.51 -5.85,-3.07 -5.85,3.07 1.12,-6.51 -4.74,-4.62 6.54,-0.95 2.93,-5.9200003 2.93,5.9200003 6.54,0.95 z" style="transform-origin: center; transform-box:fill-box;" >
    <animateTransform id="an_T3"
   attributeName="transform" 
   attributeType="XML" 
   type="scale"
   dur="1s" 
   values="1;0;1"
   repeatCount="indefinite" 
   begin="0.4s"  
   keyTimes="0;0.75;1"/>
  <animate id="an_Op3"
   attributeName="opacity"
   values="1;0;1" 
   dur="1s"
   repeatCount="indefinite" 
   begin="0.4s"
   keyTimes="0;0.75;1"  
   /> 
 </path> 
  
</svg>
</div>
```

**Update**

According to the remark in the comment, moved the styles inside svg

Comment: Yes, thank you for your answer. I could get the svg file working when i copied the CSS into the <path> with style="transform-origin: center; transform-box:fill-box;". Because it is not possible to CSS the elements inside the svg file from outside. Please adjust your code like that, then i can mark it as the solution.

Comment: @Joannis I was about to post this answer